# Remove Spacing Between Rectangle's in a TilePane - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

This is my first post, so please forgive any mistakes I make. Using Java, I've made a recreation of the classic arcade game, Snake. The game mechanics, title screen, and end screen all function properly and look correct; however, my game board currently looks horrendous.

I implemented the game's board by making a TilePane that holds a certain width and height of Rectangles. For some reason, I can clearly see a separation between each Rectangle where the background of the Region containing the TilePane peeps through. To understand how I formatted the board, here's the code where I place each Rectangle in the TilePane:

```
private final Rectangle[][] board; // board containing the Rectangles

public Board(int width, int height) {
    // grid to display each Rectangle
    TilePane playableGrid = new TilePane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    playableGrid.setPrefRows(height);
    this.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);

    // initialize the board of Rectangles
    board = new Rectangle[width][height];

    // places each Rectangle in the board and playableGrid
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            board[x][y] = new Rectangle(24, 24);
            playableGrid.getChildren().add(board[x][y]);
        } // for
    } // for

    this.getChildren().add(playableGrid); // add the playableGrid in the VBox
} // Board
```

Also, here's a link showing how the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IssvW.jpg. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I fiddled around with the Stroke property found in the Shape class, but I could not find any solution.

Edit: I'll provide a minimal reproducible example of the code to display the problem. Also, I forgot to mention that I'm using XMing to run the Application on a Windows laptop. Here's a quick example that you should be able to copy and paste into a class (it shows one extra Rectangle on the right, not sure why):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Example.class, args);
    }

    public Example() {}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        /** Setup TilePane where game would be played */
        TilePane playableGrid = new TilePane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        playableGrid.setPrefRows(25);
        for (int x = 0; x < 25; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 25; y++) {
                // The playableGrid consists of 25 rows of Rectangles
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(20, 20);
                rectangle.setFill(Color.CADETBLUE);
                playableGrid.getChildren().add(rectangle);
            } // for
        } // for
        /** In my game, a Region with a specific background holds the playableGrid */
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setMinSize(500, 500);
        root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.AZURE,
                CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        root.getChildren().add(playableGrid);
        /** Setup scene */
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        /** Setup stage */
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> Platform.exit());
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Clearly, you can see the background of the VBox holding the TilePane.

Comment: I put your code in a runnable app and ran it.  It did not produce the image you display.  On my test, there were no gaps between the rectangles in the tile pane.  Please update your question with code which can be copy and pasted to reproduce the issue without change or addition (a [mcve]).

Comment: I added a quick example that you can copy and paste!

Comment: It doesn't display the exact image I have, but do you see a gap between each Rectangle where the background appears? If not, do you think the issue could be how my code maps to my monitor or something? I've only been coding for a year.

Comment: I tested your code and do not see any lines either.

Comment: I also do not see any gaps between the Rectangles, and I do not seen an extra Rectangle on the right or anywhere else.  Tried it with JavaFX 8 and JavaFX 17.

Comment: Forgive me for making this difficult, sorry ya'll. Here's a link to exactly what I see when I run the Example program: https://imgur.com/a/Y7r2XLu.

Comment: It is obviously environmental.  What is your environment? What is the type and versions for JDK/JavaFX/OS/Graphics Hardware?  You can edit the question again to add that info.